# Finite discontinuities and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If {fn} converges pointwise to f and each {fn} has fewer than fixed natural M discontinuities, what is a counter example to f having fewer than M discontinuities?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic example for $M=1$ is $\{f_n\}$, $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ as follows:
$$
f_n(x) = x^n
$$
and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if $0\le x<1$}\\1&\text{if $x=1$}\end{cases}
$$
Then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for each $x$. Each $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, while $f$ is discontinuous at $x=1$.